# ¿Cómo imprimir un Map de arrays?

Tags: java, string, java-8

Me gustaría saber cuál es la mejor forma de imprimir un array de strings. Sé que la clase Array no sobrecarga el método toString, y que tal vez sería más correcto usar una Collection en lugar de un array de strings. Pero en el cáso de código legacy, ¿qué puedo hacer? ¿Iterar y usar java.util.Arrays.toString(array);?

Por ejemplo:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    final Object[] array = new Object[] {"hep", 1, true};
    map.put("array", array);
    System.out.println(map);
}
```

Salida:

```
{array=[Ljava.lang.Object;@6c22c95b}
```

Comment: Piensa que eso llama al toString del array que lo que hace es llamar al toString de cada objeto del array, como tienes un array de "Object" entonces llama al toString genérico y por lo tanto te sale una descripción o la referencia de memoria.

Comment: Puedes probar a crear una clase, por ejemplo "Valor" y sobreescribir el método toString y desde ahí podrás decidir qué mostrar a la hora de hacer un toString del array completo

Answer (score 2):

Algo así te podría valer:

```
map.values().stream().forEach(miArray->Arrays.asList(miArray).stream().forEach(System.out::println));
```

Eso sí, el resultado va a seguir siendo poco legible al ser los arrays de tipo Object, sin un toString() que aporte información más amigable.

Comment: Deberías advertir que sólo le servirá si efectivamente usa Java 1.8.

Comment: La pregunta está etiquetada como Java8, doy por hecho que la versión de Java no va a ser problema.

Comment: Ya sé que lleva esa etiqueta, por eso puse "efectivamente", pero otra persona puede entrar con el mismo problema sin verla o podría estar mal etiquetada la pregunta. Nunca está de más advertir cuando se usan funciones nuevas.

Comment: @Awes0meM4 el problema sería de la otra persona por no leer la información completa de la pregunta.

Comment: Además deja claro en la pregunta que lo quiere con código legacy.

Comment: Lo del código legacy parece aludir a la imposibilidad de usar Collection en vez de String[], no a la versión de Java.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza estamos aquí para solucionar problemas de otros miembros, independientemente de su origen. He puesto este comentario porque si se pone: **"este código funciona desde Java 1.8"** la respuesta está más completa y con 5 palabras y 2 números hemos resuelto ese otro problema (y es mucho menos que la pila de comentarios que están surgiendo). No obstante si os empeñáis en no ponerlo cada uno puede hacer lo que quiera y por eso no la he editado, pero si un comentario de otro mejora una respuesta mía, siempre lo he añadido y lo he agradecido.

Comment: @Awes0meM4n sí, y tenemos reglas para ello. Las etiquetas son **parte de estas reglas**. Más bien, si colocara la respuesta clásica con un recorrido en `for`, debería decir "para Java 7 y anterior se hace así". Es cuestión de perspectiva. Esta respuesta, en mi opinión, es válida tal y como luce.

Answer (score 1):

Estás diciendo que quieres imprimir `Array` de `String` y en tu ejemplo es de tipo `Object`. Te pongo un ejemplo para poder imprimir el `Array` de tipo `String[]`:

```
final Map<String, String[]> map = new HashMap<String, String[]>();
final String[] array = new String[] {"hep", "hop", "hip"};
map.put("array", array);
for (Map.Entry<String, String[]> entry : map.entrySet()) {
  System.out.println("ARRAY =>" + entry.getKey()); //Key del MAP
  for (int j=0; j<entry.getValue().length;j++){
    System.out.println(entry.getValue()[j]);
  }
}
```

La salida sería:

> ARRAY => array 
> hep
>  hop  
>  hip

Answer (score 0):

No sé qué formato deseas que imprima, pero quizá este método te valga.

```
static void printMapOfArrays(HashMap<String, Object[]> map){
      map.keySet().stream().forEach( (key) -> {
                System.out.println(key+" : "
                        +Arrays.toString(map.get(key)));
            }
      );
}
```

Si el HashMap sólo va a contener como valores un array, lo iniciaría de esta forma:

```
final Map<String, Object[]> map = new HashMap<>();
        final Object[] array = new Object[]{"help",1,true};
        final Object[] array2 = new Object[]{"help",3,false};
        map.put("array", array);
        map.put("array2", array2);

printMapOfArrays(map);
```

El resultado seríaeste:

array : [help, 1, true] 
array2 : [help, 3, false]